# Laser diode control without PD

Tags: photodiode, optics, laser-diode, optimization, laser-driver

I'm currently looking for a new light source for a system. The laser diode seems to be an excellent candidate. However, for the specific wavelength I need (488 nm), diodes with an integrated photodiode cost 10 times more than a diode without one.

I want to use this diode in constant current mode and control its operation by the input current.

I need this circuit to be deployable on several devices and to provide identical optical power. Do you think this can be achieved without a photodiode?

Comment: What power of laser? Is this in a product?

Comment: Define "identical". There always has to be some amount of acceptable tolerance.

Comment: The power required is not yet precise, but it’s between 200 and 400 mW, and the laser will actually be placed inside a product.

Comment: We can accept a tolerance of +-10mW for a laser diode of 200mW.

Comment: Very likely this can be achieved. So what is the real question?

Comment: Can you pick off part of the beam and use an external PD for power control?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. In that case, what's the point of using a PD if you can accept a tolerance of +-10mW? And why are most laser diodes made with a PD?  I suppose every company would rather buy a laser diode for $300 than $3000.

Using an external PD could be an option, but the main problem I see with this solution is that the PD will have to be calibrated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to reach out to the manufacturer.  The optical output power with a given current can change due to a number of factors, including temperature and operating lifetime, that's why integrated PDs are used. The manufacturer should be able to tell you the maximum change over time as well as the part to part variance.